# Regular expression to match question mark except repeated or commented(--)

Tags: regex

I would like to build a regular expression in C# to match question mark except repeated or commented.
For example, if I have a string below

```
--???
??
asdlfkj --?
asldfjl -?
aslfldkf --?
aslfkvlv --??
?
-?
dklsafdlafjd = ?
```

, I want to match like below (between * character).

```
--???
??
asdlfkj --?
asldfjl -*?*
aslfldkf --?
aslfkvlv --??
*?*
-*?*
dklsafdlafjd = *?*
```

I'm developing SQL binding method using 2 parameters.

The first one is SQL, for example

```
select * from atable where id = ?.
```

SQL can have comment so I want ignore them.

The second one is parameter for SQL as Array to match sequentially;

Does anyone have good idea for it?

Comment: What happens if a line has more than one match?  What about a line which has both a match and non match?

Comment: It is unclear because you have not specified the programming language, and what you are actually doing (as you have not posted your code/patterns that failed).

Answer (score 1):

If you can negate this regex it should work for you:

```
(\?{2,}|(?<=--)\?)
```

I don't know what language you're working in, but you should be able to `filter` by line. Apply this regex as a predicate and either negate it or use a `exclude` function.

I'll leave those implementation details up to you.